# can't POST item price in paypal sandbox

Tags: paypal, sandbox

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="YYHZM9FTBZQGW">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="20.00">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif"    border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

this is a paypal sandbox button. all i want to do is to post the TOTAL price of all the product the user buy in my website.

I created a button with nothing to post because basically i want to post dynamically in the future using a php variable so I think I don't need to set up the item price, name, quantity in the sandbox create button features. how am i suppose to do that.

[image: paypal sandbox]

this is the output. I want the item price to be not editable same as with description and quantity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't override the amount dynamically, is because you have a so-called 'PayPal hosted button'.
With a hosted button, the amount is stored on PayPal's side and can't be overwritten with the 'amount' variable.
You'll either want to use a non-hosted button, or use the [BMUpdateButton](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_BMUpdateButton) API call to dynamically update the button's amount.

An example request for BMUpdateButton would look as follows:

```
USER=Your API username
PWD=Your API password
SIGNATURE=Your API signature
VERSION=82.0
HOSTEDUBTTONID=The value of <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="">
BUTTONTYPE=The type of button. E.g. BUYNOW
BUTTONCODE=The type of code you want to get back. E.g. HOSTED
L_BUTTONVAR0=amount=The new amount with a period as separator
L_BUTTONVAR1=item_name=Optional: a new item name if you wish
```

Similary, you could also use the [BMCreateButton](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_BMCreateButton) API to create a new button, or use the [BMButtonSearch](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_BMButtonSearch) API to search through a list of all your stored hosted buttons (to find the hosted_button_id of your button automatically, for example)

The reason to use a hosted button is because it's more secure. A non-hosted, unencrypted button would basically leave the amounts open to manipulation. Fraudulent transactions waiting to happen.

Comment: i get it now and it really the problem of the hosted_id. i started to branch every details out using input names, I'll just implement this method when we still have time. our defense will be on thursday and we still have many modules left behind. THANKS!