# paypal custom amount variable BMUpdate?

Tags: php, paypal, sandbox

Here is the generated code for my sandbox buy now button.  I have added another hidden input `amount`, which will contain a variable with the total amount(no set prices on my website) to be sent to paypal.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" id="paypal-container-2" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="EJWG97W7YUN4G">
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $total; ?>" />
            <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
            <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
            </form>
```

From reading a similar question [can't POST item price in paypal sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438868/cant-post-item-price-in-paypal-sandbox) , this way leaves the hidden input `amount` open to manipulation by the user?  The answer was to use BMUpdateButton API to update the buttons amount.   I don't know how to implement BMUpdateButton API into PHP.  How do i accomplish this with PHP?  Is there a tutorial?  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

heres the basics lol the other function decode will also be needed

```
function updateItemPP($buttoncode, $amount, $item_name)

{

$API_USERNAME ="yourname";

$API_PASSWORD = "yourpassY";

$API_SIGNATURE = "yoursig";

$API_ENDPOINT = 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp';

$VERSION = '60.0';



$ch=curl_init();



curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$API_ENDPOINT);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$nvpreq="USER=".urlencode($API_USERNAME)."&PWD=".urlencode($API_PASSWORD)."&SIGNATURE=".urlencode($API_SIGNATURE)."&VERSION=".urlencode($VERSION)."&METHOD=BMCreateButton&HOSTEDBUTTONID=".urlencode($buttoncode)."&BUTTONTYPE=BUYNOW&L_BUTTONVAR1=amount=".urlencode($amount)."&L_BUTTONVAR2=item_name=".urlencode($item_name);

echo "here is the request string:\n".$nvpreq;

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$nvpreq);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

$response = urldecode($response);

echo "this is update response".$response;

$nvpResArray=$this->deformat($response);

$ack = ($nvpResArray["ACK"]);

$HostedButtonID=($nvpResArray["HOSTED_BUTTON_ID"]);

if ($ack=="FAILOR")

return "failor";

else 

return $HostedButtonID;

}
```

this function was not written by me but another user here

```
static function deformat( $str )
    {
        $result = array();

        while ( strlen( $str ) ) {
            // postion of key

            $keyPos = strpos( $str, '=' );

            // position of value
            $valPos = strpos( $str, '&' ) ? strpos( $str, '&' ): strlen( $str );

            /*getting the Key and Value values and storing in a Associative Array*/
            $key = substr( $str, 0, $keyPos );
            $val = substr( $str, $keyPos + 1, $valPos - $keyPos - 1 );

            //decoding the respose
            $result[ strtoupper( urldecode( $key ) ) ] = urldecode( $val );
            $str = substr( $str, $valPos + 1, strlen( $str ) );
            //echo  substr( $str, $valPos + 1, strlen( $str ) );
        }


        return $result;
    }
```

this should help but it also returns a new buttoncode so be sure to include that into the button call on your page

Answer (score 0):

Having the payment amount as an input in this way (even as a hidden field), is insecure and could lead to a hacker paying £0.1 for an item which should cost +£100... and receiving the goods in full!

My method to protect against this is to have your Buy Now payment button POST to a processing page. When a user agrees to purchase an item, the total should be calculated and stored in a database linked to a unique identifier. The processing page will use the identifier to pull the total amount from the database and use this value for payment. When the payment data (such as business_email and amount) is validated, the user is redirected to PayPal to complete the payment - with the untouched amount to pay.

I hope this helps!